# It's possible to detect TLS version on secure requests at controller's layer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, tls1.2

I have a Rails API running on a Heroku instance that needs to verify if all requests are being transported securely using TLS v1.2.

I don't know if this is possible to do at application controller's layer on a RoR app, it should be configured in server's layer but Heroku doesn't provide support to configure this option.

I found how to force access to the app to use SSL, but couldn't found this option for TLS.

I would like to say that I'm not an expert on security neither server's configuration.

It's possible to detect TLS version on secure requests at controller's layer?

Answer (score -1):

If you run Passenger on Heroku, it allows custom nginx config:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template

I haven't tried but I imagine you'd just configure which protocols you allow:

```
server {
  ...
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ...
}
```